# AlertDialog doesn't wrap my content

Tags: android, layout, android-alertdialog

I'm using an alert dialog to display a view with spinner to set the period and the scale of a chart

But it doesn't wrap my content and all the tuto I tried failed...

**My code**

```
        LinearLayout vue = new LinearLayout(context);
        vue.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        vue.addView(diag.getView());

        choixPeriode = (Spinner) vue.findViewById(R.id.spinner_periode);
        choixEchelle = (Spinner) vue.findViewById(R.id.spinner_echelle);
        if(choixEchelle == null)
            choixEchelle = new Spinner(context);
        final int oldPeriode = DiagramController.PeriodeToPos(this.periode);
        final int oldEchelle = DiagramController.echelleToPos(this.echelle);
        choixPeriode.setSelection(oldPeriode);
        choixEchelle.setSelection(oldEchelle);


        LinearLayout containerButton = new LinearLayout(context);
        containerButton.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        final ImageView croix = ((ImageView) vue.findViewById(R.id.croix));
        final Button ok = new Button(context);
        ok.setText(R.string.valider);
        final Button cancel = new Button(context);
        cancel.setText(android.R.string.cancel);

        containerButton.addView(ok);
        containerButton.addView(cancel);

        vue.addView(containerButton);

        AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        dialogBuilder.setView(vue);

        final AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        lp.copyFrom(alertDialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
        lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        alertDialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
        alertDialog.show();

        croix.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                alertDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                periode = DiagramController.posToPeriode(choixPeriode.getSelectedItemPosition());
                echelle = DiagramController.posToEchelle(choixEchelle.getSelectedItemPosition());
                changePeriode();
                alertDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                alertDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
```

diag.getView() return a LinearLayout with the title, the spinners and the chart.

**Result in portrait**
[image: Result in portrait]

**Result in landscape**
[image: Result in landscape]

**Result with custom Dialog**

[image]

Comment: I would suggest making a custom dialog(Maybe you already tried it). If you don't know how to do it, I will post the code for you.

Comment: I thought about it but I don't know how to do. There is no simple solution ?

Comment: It is simple, I will post you the code. Give me a minute.

Answer (score 1):

1.) You will need to create a custom xml layout.

2.) Create a new class. And write your code in the onCreate.

```
public class MyDialog extends Dialog {

private TextView textView;

private Context context;

public MyDialog(Context context) {
    super(context);

    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);

    //Your code
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);


}
}
```

Comment: Let me know if it helped you.

Comment: It works perfectly !! Thank you a lot ! I didn't used XML. I added a field `View` in the constructor and I set the contentView with it

Comment: can I set the size of my custom dialog ? I tried to use `getWindow.setLayout` but it doesn't have any effect

Comment: What do you exactly want to achieve?

Comment: I updated my post with a picture when I use the custom dialog

Comment: If i understood it correctly, set the minWidth and minHeight for the container layout